# What are ways to protect a novel program solution in order to protect the IP investment of development effort?

Tags: program, security

If a team of developers invest a lot of time to build a unique solution to solve a problem, what ways can investors in their efforts protect the effective IP of that work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there anything that prevents popular programs from being cloned hundreds of times by copycats?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/687/is-there-anything-that-prevents-popular-programs-from-being-cloned-hundreds-of-t)

Comment: @HenryE they submitted both questions...

Comment: @sohrab - Please see my edit above. When both questions existed inside of the same question, the community flagged it as not focused and told me to post them as separate questions. The community cannot later tell me that they are the same question because that would be a contradiction. If some manner of arbitration is needed to resolve how to handle these questions, that is beyond my expertise.

Comment: All good. This isn't a hive mind. We don't have to all agree :)

Comment: @sohrab - Thank you for your understanding. This dilemma transcends me, so I have opened a meta for the community to help resolve it: https://solana.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/how-do-we-properly-handle-the-tug-of-war-between-questions-closed-that-are-not-f

Comment: This isn't an investment forum. I recommend rewording the question so it is specific to developing IP on Solana.

Comment: I started to realize that after I broke the original Solana question into the 3 questions, per the suggestion given to me. (See my comment above.) That is a good catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience is that marketing, hype, and TVL are at least as important as the IP itself. But to answer your question directly: there's nothing you can do. Information wants to be free.